# Java replaceAll() method

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I am trying to understand this piece of codes:

```
for (File f : files) {
     fileName = f.getName().toUpperCase().replaceAll("_\\d\\d\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d", "");

     if (fileName.equals(tableName + ".XML")) {
         returnFile = f;
         break;
     }
}
```

and I am stuck at this part: `replaceAll("_\\d\\d\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d", "")`

as far as I know it is trying to remove something from the name (maybe the underscore "_" ) but what exactly is `_\\d\\d\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d`

Can somebody please explain?

Comment: Learn about regexes.

Comment: This code now has two problems.

Comment: @jdv what are those two problems you are seeing?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.replaceAll("_\\d\\d\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d", "")` takes the string `str` and replaces all matches of the regular expression `_\d\d\d\d_\d\d_\d\d_\d\d_\d\d` with nothing (i.e. `""`). (The reason it is written `\\d` and not `\d` is that the `\` is escaped.)

In this case, `\d` means "a digit". So, more than likely, it removes a date/time from the string. For an example, if `str` is `"screenshot_from_stackoverflow_2016_03_30_23_47.jpg"`, it becomes `screenshot_from_stackoverflow.jpg` after the `replaceAll`.

To get a feel for regular expressions, how they work and what they can do, I would recommend reading up on them, for instance on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). It has a pretty comprehensive [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html) available.

Comment: Actually, it will become `SCREENSHOT_FROM_STACKOVERFLOW.JPG` as he is also doing `toUpperCase()` before `replaceAll()`.

Comment: @user2004685 In the example provided in the question, yes. :) This answer only really covers the `replaceAll`-part, as it was the part being asked about.

Comment: I'm not correcting you. Just saying for common understand if anyone is interested. :)

Answer (score 1):

> as far as I know it is trying to remove something from the name (maybe the underscore "_" ) but what exactly is *\d\d\d\d*\d\d_\d\d_\d\d_\d\d

It is the pattern which will match the digits `[0-9]` in this format `_XXXX_XX_XX_XX_` and replace it with `""` i.e. nothing.

For Example,

```
_7686_77_78_77_77
_0123_65_58_56_12
```

Will be replaced in your string with `""`.

Answer (score 1):

\d - matches a digit [0-9]

[Java RegEx](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)